# Cannot add a new User to Users table in Postgresql using SQLalchemy after switching from SQlite

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've recently ported SQLite setup to PostgreSQL in order to deploy my project to Heroku.

**Class definition:**

```
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    #__tablename__ = 'Users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

Signup function:

```html
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = Users(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password) #password=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
```

Currently, whenever I'm trying to register a new user I'm getting:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, username, email, sha256$pRstOqmm$d077bce846881e92caffe0c120baf3808c67c01c6652e85c...).
```

Comment: You table uses id as a primary key, yet you are not providing it. It may help if you add a default to this column and set it to a sequence which will provide unique values.

Comment: How did you create your tables? In its default value of `autoincrement='auto'` a non composite primary key Column of integer type receives auto incrementing behavior. In case of Postgresql a suitable serial column is used. Please include your actual schema as seen in the DB.